# UIActivityIndicatorView subview disappears before NSOperationQueue is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsoperationqueue, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to get a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to show on screen while my CSV import method is running, but I can't get it right. With the code below, the ActivityIndicator subview shows for a second or so then disappears, even if the import operation is still running. How can I make it stay on screen until the `NSOperationQueue` is finished? I'm using iOS 7.1 on my test device.

User taps 'Yes' on an `UIAlertView` to import the data:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if(buttonIndex == 0){
    //clicked Yes
    [self loadingSpinner];

    operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *importOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(importCSVData:) object:self.importURL];
    [operationQueue addOperation:importOperation];

}
else if(buttonIndex == 1){
    //clicked No

}
}
```

Method to show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` on top of everything else on screen:

```
-(void)loadingSpinner{
self.overlayView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];

UIView *topView = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    self.overlayView.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
}
else{
    self.overlayView.frame = topView.frame;
}

[self.overlayView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
self.spinner.center = self.overlayView.center;
[self.overlayView addSubview:self.spinner];
[self.spinner startAnimating];

[topView addSubview:self.overlayView];

}
```

At the end of the import operation to remove the activity indicator:

```
[self.overlayView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: [self.queue.operations count] == 0 then stop spinner

Answer (score 0):

Use addOperationWithBlock: method on NSOperationQueue with which you will have more control. You would edit your code like this to use block version,

```
 NSOperationQueue *queue =  [NSOperationQueue new];
  [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
      [self loadingSpinner];
    }];
    [self importCSVData:self.importUrl];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
      [self.overlay removeFromSuperView];
    }];
  }];
```

Comment: No change, the activity indicator shows for a second or so then disappears, with the data continuing to import in the background.

Comment: Then there is something else that you have been doing wrong. The UIActivityIndicatorView is a very simple class with few properties and adding it appropriately should show it animating.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GCD to implement this task.

Create dispatch queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("Other Q", NULL);
```

or you can use the main queue like:

```
dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

Finally replace your code with the following:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
      [self loadingSpinner];
     });

    [self importCSVData:self.importURL];

    });
```

You might want to check for the title of you button clicked on your UIAlertView.
To do so change this:

```
if(buttonIndex == 1)
```

With this:

```
if([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]isEqual:@"YES"])
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately - the data is imported, but the activity indicator view doesn't show at all.

Comment: That is because all UI updates has to be executed on the main thread. I've made some changes on the code above. Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: No, still the same. There's obviously something else going on that I'm missing.